# Python/Cassandra: insert vs. CSV import

Tags: python, cassandra, load-testing

I am generating load test data in a Python script for Cassandra.

Is it better to insert directly into Cassandra from the script, or to write a CSV file and then load that via Cassandra?

This is for a couple million rows.

Comment: When a decision like this looks too hard, it may be not that important. =) I'd go with the one that looks easiest -- after you try something, you'll know better if you need to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

For a few million, I'd say just use CSV (assuming rows aren't huge); and see if it works. If not, inserts it is :)

For more heavy duty stuff, you might want to create sstables and use sstable loader.